# Way to determine the type of an object and then cast an object from snake yaml.load(InputStream)

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

So I'm writing this utility class for all my model objects to inherit from so that whenever I call saveToFile(filename) it will save that object in a yaml format. To String just outputs the file in yaml format. What I really want to be able to do though is initialize all the attributes of an object with the attributes in a file but I don't want to have to know what type of object it is beforehand.

I want a method something along the lines of

```
public void loadFromFile(String filename){
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        Yaml y = new Yaml();
        this = y.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

this works fine, save for the fact that you can't assign an object to "this".

Comment: What type of Object does y.load(input) return?

Comment: @jzd - it returns `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to cast:

```
YourObject object = (YourObject) y.load(input);
```

Also, don't do assignments to `this`. Instead you should load the object externally and use something like `BeanUtils.copyProperties(object, yamlObject)`

Also take a look at the [yamlbeans](http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/).

Btw, in order to make a utility method, your cast won't work like that. You'd better pass a `Class<T>` argument to the method, and let it have return type `T`. The use `clazz.cast(..)` to do the cast.